# Node.js, Windows, fs.open() - unwanted read-only flag on newly-created file

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

I'm having trouble working out why Windows is creating a new file with the read-only attribute set. What I want is exclusive random-access write permissions to a file that I'll be using as a simple file-based data store. I'm fine with other processes reading from it, but I only want a single process to be able to write to it.

I've tried several different variations of the open flags, but **no matter what I do, Windows seems to be setting a read-only attribute on the file**. As such, **after closing the file, attempts to reopen it for writing fail**. I understand that I could manually try to manipulate the attribute after the fact, but this is backwards. I don't want the attribute to appear in the first place. When I close the file, it should be safe for someone else to open for writing.

```
FS.open(filePath + '.lock', 'w+', 6, (err, fd) => {
  if (err) console.log('failed to open lock file', err);
  else {
    console.log('successfully opened lock file');
    setTimeout(() => {
      FS.close(fd, () => {
        console.log(`closed lock file`);
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`attempt reopening the file...`);
          FS.open(filePath + '.lock', 'w+', 6, (err, fd) => {
            if (err) console.log('failed to open lock file', err);
            else {
              console.log(`file closed successfully`);
              FS.closeSync(fd);
            }
          });
        }, 500);
      });
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Output:

```
successfully opened lock file
closed lock file
attempt reopening the file...
failed to open lock file [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\salix\test.data.lock'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\dev\\test.data.lock'
}
```

[image: unwanted read-only attribute]

As you can see, the file seems to have the read-only attribute set, even after the file is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Set the file mode to `0o644` so you can read and write to it, but others can only read. Setting the value to just `6` does not give you (the owner of the file) any read or write permissions and thus the EPERM issue you run into when you try to open it yourself after creating it.

It looks to me like your file mode values are not correct.  When you set it to `6`, that defines read and write for others, but does not define read and write for yourself.

There's a pretty good description of how they work [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_modes).

You basically want three octal values.  The left most one is for you (the owner).  The middle one is for the group.  The right one is for others.  So, `0o644` gives you the owner read and write and group and others only read.

As a test harness to try different modes, I used this program:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function run() {
    const mode = 0o644;
    const fileHandle1 = await fsp.open("test.lock", "w+", mode);
    console.log("file open first time");
    await fileHandle1.close();
    console.log("file closed first time");

    await delay(500);

    const fileHandle2 = await fsp.open("test.lock", "w+", mode);
    console.log("file open second time");
    await fileHandle2.close();
    console.log("file closed second time");
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

FYI, node.js has [named constants](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_modes) for the different permissions which might make the code more readable in the long run than just using octal digits.

Comment: Hmm, still not seeing any exclusivity. I have two separate write-enabled file descriptors successfully opened for the same lock file.

Comment: @NathanRidley - Two write-enabled file descriptors in the same process?  Or in different processes.  I guess I'm confused about what problem you're trying to solve.  I solved the issue of you couldn't open your own file.  That's what I thought you were trying to do.  Exclusivity within your process is a different set of flags.

Comment: Yeah, the first part solved, thanks :-) The bigger picture though was that I wanted a simple way to ensure that only one write handle to the file could be opened at a time. Whether in the same process or in different processes, I wanted to make sure there was never more than one writer. Since I posted this, I have found proper-lockfile on npm, so I guess I'll use that.

Answer (score 1):

The [file `mode`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) argument `6` is creating a read only file.

Use `0o600` if you want read/write for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried 0o600 and 0o200 but in both cases there is no write exclusivity.

Comment: The file modes only set file access permissions, so fixes the "read only" part of the issue. I thought write exclusivity was the default in windows land when a process opens a file for writing?

Comment: I'd have thought so too, but somehow I have two file descriptors open to the same path, both with write permissions, and both reporting success on attempts to write to the file.